# How can I enumerate rows in groups with Spark/Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'd like to enumerate grouped values just like with Pandas:

[Enumerate each row for each group in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228215/enumerate-each-row-for-each-group-in-a-dataframe)

What is a way in Spark/Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `row_number` window function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("some_column").orderBy("some_other_column")
df.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(w))
```

Comment: I suppose it works - just my Spark is too old :) I need a new Spark now.

Comment: It looks I've missed part of the conversation but window functions require Spark 1.4+.

Comment: row_number even 1.6.0. So I have a reason to get that.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this on rdd level by doing:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(['a', 'b', 'c'])
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd.zipWithIndex())
df.show()
```

It will result:

`+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  a|  0|
|  b|  1|
|  c|  2|
+---+---+`

If you only need unique ID, not real continuous indexing, you may also use
`zipWithUniqueId()` which is more efficient, since done locally on each partition.

Comment: Note that since pyspark 1.6 the `pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id` function is also available.