# Enumerate rows for each dtaaframe group based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I would like to reenumerate rows in given `df` using some conditions. My question is an extension of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228215/enumerate-each-row-for-each-group-in-a-dataframe).

Example of `df`:

```
   ind  seq  status 
0   1   2    up
1   1   3    mid
2   1   5    down
3   2   1    up
4   2   2    mid
5   2   3    down
6   3   1    up
7   3   2    mid
8   3   3    oth
```

The `df` contains `ind` column which represents a **group**.  The `seq` column might have some bad data. That's way I would like to add another column `seq_corr` to correct the `seq` enumerating based on some conditions:

- the first value in a group in `status` column equals `up`
- the last value in a group in `status` column equals `down` OR `oth`
- in all other cases copy number from `seq` column.

I know the logical way to do this but I have some troubles how to convert it to `Python`. Especially when it comes to proper slicing and accessing the first and the last element of each group.

Below you can find my not working code:

```
 def new_id(x):
    if (x.loc['status',0] == 'up') and ((x.loc['status',-1]=='down') or (x['status',-1]=='oth')):
        x['ind_corr'] = np.arange(1, len(x) + 1)
    else:
        x['seq_corr']= x['seq']
    return x

 df.groupby('ind', as_index=False).apply(new_id)
```

Expected result:

```
   ind  seq  status  seq_corr
0   1   2    up       1
1   1   3    mid      2
2   1   5    down     3
3   2   1    up       1
4   2   2    mid      2
5   2   3    down     3
6   3   5    up       1
7   3   2    mid      2
8   3   7    oth      3
```

Hoping that someone would be able to point me out any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `df.groupby` followed by an `apply` and `concatenat`ion.

```
vals = df.groupby('ind').apply(
       lambda g: np.where(g['status'].iloc[0] == 'up' 
                       or g['status'].iloc[-1] in {'down', 'oth'},
      np.arange(1, len(g) + 1), g['seq'])
).values

df['seq_corr'] = np.concatenate(vals)
```

---

```
df
   ind  seq status  seq_corr
0    1    2     up         1
1    1    3    mid         2
2    1    5   down         3
3    2    1     up         1
4    2    2    mid         2
5    2    3   down         3
6    3    1     up         1
7    3    2    mid         2
8    3    3    oth         3
```

Comment: Thank you it works very nice ! Just one question. What should I do if I want to copy `seq` number if the `status` does not meet any condition ?

Comment: @Michal its simple replace `or` with `and`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I did a bit of editing to your answer. You can edit it in your words.

Comment: @Bharathshetty the boolean expressions are all right. There must stay or. This code reenumerates all seq numbers.

Comment: @Michal will my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Another method with groupby cumcount. To select the first and last row we can use head and tail method and union their indices.  I think this one might help with your second question

```
df['seq_corr'] = df.groupby('ind').cumcount()+1
idx = df.groupby('ind').head(1).index.union(df.groupby('ind').tail(1).index)

df.loc[idx,'seq_corr'] = np.where(~df.loc[idx,'status'].isin(['up','down','oth']),
                                    df.loc[idx,'seq'],df.loc[idx,'seq_corr'])
```

Sample Output:

```
   ind  seq status  seq_corr
0    1    2     up         1
1    1    3    mid         2
2    1    5  dance         5
3    2    1     up         1
4    2    2    mid         2
5    2    3   down         3
6    3    1     up         1
7    3    2    mid         2
8    3    3    oth         3
```

Comment: Thank you @Bharath shetty. Does `isin([...])` takes into account all conditions with `AND` statement ? My idea was to also have `OR`. But anyway I have merged @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ answer with my idea and it looks like everything works fine. I will post the solution below.

Comment: This will work fine based on your `OR` condition, since we are taking first and last row of grouped data. This was the desired output right? Any problem you faced?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have corrected my code. Looking at first tests, everything is ok.

```
 def new_id(x):
    if (x['status'].iloc[0] == 'up') and ((x['status'].iloc[-1]=='down') or (x['status'].iloc[-1]=='oth')):
    x['seq_corr'] = np.arange(1, len(x) + 1)
    else:
    x['seq_corr']= x['seq']
    return x
```