# Pandas: Populate rows for same index in a group with different values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Sample df**:

```
In [2004]: df
Out[2004]: 
   index table_name column_name data_type  default  max_length
0      0   f_person      active   integer      NaN         NaN
1      0   f_person        actv   integer      NaN         NaN
2      5   f_person         ssn   varchar      NaN       256.0
3      5   f_person         ssn   varchar      NaN        99.0
4      6   f_person          pl   varchar     10.0       256.0
5      6   f_person          pl    bigint      NaN       256.0
6      8   f_person      prefix   varchar      NaN       256.0
7      8   f_person      prefix   integer      NaN       256.0
```

For the same index, I want to add a new column `schema` and populate different values for each row. Number of rows per group will be always `<= 2`.

**Expected Output**:

```
In [2006]: df
Out[2006]: 
   index table_name column_name data_type  default  max_length schema
0      0   f_person      active   integer      NaN         NaN     s1
1      0   f_person        actv   integer      NaN         NaN     s2
2      5   f_person         ssn   varchar      NaN       256.0     s1
3      5   f_person         ssn   varchar      NaN        99.0     s2
4      6   f_person          pl   varchar     10.0       256.0     s1
5      6   f_person          pl    bigint      NaN       256.0     s2
6      8   f_person      prefix   varchar      NaN       256.0     s1
7      8   f_person      prefix   integer      NaN       256.0     s2
```

I solved it using a for loop, but there must be a better way. Can someone please suggest a more pandaic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to populate from a list a defined values:

```
values = ['s1', 's2']

d = dict(enumerate(values))

df['schema'] = df.groupby('index').cumcount().map(d)
```

Otherwise, this is already covered in [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228215/enumerate-each-row-for-each-group-in-a-dataframe)

output:

```
   index table_name column_name data_type  default  max_length schema
0      0   f_person      active   integer      NaN         NaN     s1
1      0   f_person        actv   integer      NaN         NaN     s2
2      5   f_person         ssn   varchar      NaN       256.0     s1
3      5   f_person         ssn   varchar      NaN        99.0     s2
4      6   f_person          pl   varchar     10.0       256.0     s1
5      6   f_person          pl    bigint      NaN       256.0     s2
6      8   f_person      prefix   varchar      NaN       256.0     s1
7      8   f_person      prefix   integer      NaN       256.0     s2
```

Comment: @Mayank great! Note that you need to know in advance the number of values (or use the dictionary `get` method to avoid KeyError)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `groupby.cumcount()` which performs a grouped cumulative count and concatenate that with a simple 's':

```
df['schema'] = 's' + df.groupby('index').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)

df[['index','schema']]
Out[53]: 
   index schema
0      0     s1
1      0     s2
2      5     s1
3      5     s2
4      6     s1
5      6     s2
6      8     s1
7      8     s2
```

I have a feeling I might be misuderstanding your question, so apologies, if that.